# 'ORA-02376: invalid or redundant resource' occurs on execute immediate

Tags: arrays, oracle12c

Problem: 'ORA-02376: invalid or redundant resource' occurs on the execute immediate (v_sql_stmt) statement.

Troubleshooting performed:  Included dbms_output.out_line (v_sql_stmt), which yields the correctly formatted commands from the array, and when copying the dbms output to manually run the commands individually outside of the array - the 9 alter profile commands execute successfully. Also, reduced array to only one value (failed_login_attempts 3), ORA error still occurs on execute immediate statement (not really an array with one value, was just trying to troubleshoot). Research of ORA-02376 states 'a resource that is not defined or that is specified twice appears in the create or alter profile statement'. The dbms_output.put_line shows that none of the resources are specified twice, and since the commands run successfully outside of the array, my thought is that they are defined.

Question: Any idea why ORA-02376 occurs on the execute immediate (v_sql_stmt) command?

DECLARE
    TYPE array_n IS VARRAY (9) OF VARCHAR2 (29);

```
array        array_n
                 := array_n ('failed_login_attempts 3',
                             'idle_time 15',
                             'password_grace_time 5',
                             'password_life_time 35',
                             'password_lock_time unlimited',
                             'password_reuse_max 1024',
                             'password_reuse_time 365',
                             'password_verify_function null',
                             'sessions_per_user 1024');
v_sql_stmt   VARCHAR (90);
v_env        VARCHAR2 (10);
v_date       DATE;
```

BEGIN
    SELECT environment INTO v_env FROM core.site;

```
IF v_env = 'PROD'
THEN
    FOR i IN 1 .. array.COUNT
    LOOP
        v_sql_stmt := 'alter profile default limit ' || array (i) || ';';
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_sql_stmt);

        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE (v_sql_stmt);
    END LOOP;
ELSE
    SELECT SYSDATE INTO v_date FROM DUAL;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (v_date);
END IF;
```

END;

---

Error at line 2
ORA-02376: invalid or redundant resource
ORA-06512: at line 27

Answer (score 2):

The sql statements in execute immediate should not have a ; at the end of each statement, so changing the following line corrected the problem...

```
v_sql_stmt := 'alter profile default limit ' || array ( I ) ;
```